# The $\infty$-category of $n$-manifolds and open embeddings determined homotopically from that of topological manifolds?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds

Let $\mathrm{Diff}_n$, $\mathrm{PL}_n$, $\mathrm{Top}_n$ denote the $\infty$-categories of $n$-manifolds which are respectively smooth/PL/topological, and open embeddings (for instance by taking the homotopy coherent nerve of the sing of the corresponding topological categories).

Let $\operatorname{BTop}(n)$ and $ \mathrm{B}O(n)$ be the classifying spaces of topological respectively orthogonal $\mathbb{R}^n$-bundles. Similarly let $\operatorname{BPL}(n)$ denote the classifying space of $\mathrm{PL}$-bundles of rank $n$ (it's not quite the classifying space of a topological group but is actually the simplicial set classifying $\mathrm{PL}$ bundles over polyhedra). Let $\mathcal{S}_{/X}$ denote the slice category of the $\infty$-category of spaces over a fixed space $X$. There's a canonical commutative diagram of $\infty$-categories (for the middle row in this diagram you have to work a bit but I'm pretty sure this is true):
$\require{AMScd}$

\begin{CD}
        \mathrm{Diff}_n @>>> \mathrm{PL}_n @>>>  \mathrm{Top}_n\\
        @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
        \mathcal{S}_{/\mathrm{B}O(n)} @>>> S_{ /\mathrm{B}\mathrm{PL}(n)} @>>> \mathcal{S}_{/\mathrm{BTop}(n)}
    \end{CD}

> **Question:** (for $n \ne 4$) Are all the squares in this diagram pullback squares? If so where can I find this or at least the relevant
>   pieces of the argument?

Comment: I think you need to replace BO, BPL and BTop by their unstable versions. Then it sounds like a reformulation of smoothing theory as in Kirby-Siebenmann (which would even work for dimension 4 when going from PL to Diff).

Comment: @skupers Having the stable versions is part of the statement which I think shiuld be true due to Product Structure theorems. Could you perhaps point at the exact statements from Kirby and Siebenmann you have in mind?

Comment: The product structure theorems give $n$-equivalences, but here you ask for full homotopy equivalences. It is true that $Top(n)/PL(n)=Top/PL=K(\mathbb Z/2,3)$, though, so that square is OK either way. Unstable PL bundles realize all Pontrjagin classes, while smooth ones don't. So there is a PL $S^3$ bundle on $S^{4n}$ with nontrivial $p_n$ that is not smoothable, but which your stable statement would imply smoothable. . . Also, $Top(n)$ probably isn't a topological group, either, and you should do something simplicial there, too.

Comment: @BenWieland I thought $BHomeo(\mathbb{R}^n)$ works. I see your point about the stability, i'll fix that.

Comment: By Kisters theorem, BTop(n) defined as classifying n-dimensional topological microbundles is weakly equivalent to BHomeo(R^n). Anyway, it's Essay V.1 you want to look at. Another reference is Lashof's Embedding Spaxes

Comment: If you really want an answer to this question, it's probably worth rephrasing to avoid mention of $\infty$-categories. I imagine there may well be somebody around who knows enough differential topology to answer the question conclusively or else explain why it's an open problem, but may not be 100% certain what is needed to get the $\infty$-categorical statement. This would be a worthwhile exercise in "compiling out" the $\infty$-categories for its own sake anyway. You could leave the $\infty$-categorical statement in, but not feature it so prominently.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the diagonal topology on $Homeo(M)$ works. I was being overcautious because a lot of people use a simplicial modification. Probably they're doing it to deal with subgroups that are not closed. But if you're only dealing with the one homotopy type, I can't see anything that could go wrong.

Comment: Remark 3.29 of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5522 claims that the answer is yes, and that this follows from Kirby-Siebenmann, but there is no precise reference. I was not able to find it in KS, but if you manage I would be quite interested to see it myself.